# A simple infinite limit question with logs

Tags: limits

$$f(n)= 3n \log\log n$$

and   $$g(n)=n (\log n)^6 + 8n^2$$ and I try to find

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)}$$

Comment: You mean $f(n)=3n\log\log n$ and $g(n)=n(\log n)^6 + 8n^2$?

Comment: @MPW Yes, I don't know how to write this porerly. Sorry about that.

Comment: No problem, just specifically wondered if the 6 was iteration or exponent.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

$$\frac{n\log\log n}{n\log^6n+8n^2}\le\frac{n\log n}{8n^2}\le\frac{1}{n^{1/2}}$$

Comment: Thank you firstly. Then can we say it goes to 0 ?

Comment: @EminÇiftçi Indeed, using for example the squeeze theorem.

Comment: Oh, okey I see now clearly. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Well, $g(n)\sim_\infty 8n^2$, hence
$$\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}\sim_\infty\frac{3n \log\log n}{8n^2}=\frac38\frac{\log\log n}{n}\to 0,$$
 as $\log\log n\in o(\log n)\in o(n)$.